# Kiota MS Graph SDK for PHP email attachments

Tags: php, sdk, microsoft-graph-api, kiota

we are using v2.3.0 and have successfully managed to authenticate and send an email.  The issue we are having is with email attachments.  The code for the attachments is as follows:

```
            $attachment = new FileAttachment();
            $attachment->setName($emailAttachment['fileName']);
            $attachment->setContentType(mime_content_type($emailAttachment['fileLocation']));
            $data = Utils::tryFopen($emailAttachment['fileLocation'], 'r');
            $resource = base64_decode($data);
            $attachment->setContentBytes(Utils::streamFor($resource));
            $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
```

The issue is the attachments are received as empty files.  We have tested with JPG, PNG, PDF and Office files and all are the same result. The attachments look correct in Outlook when received:

[image]

However the files are zero bytes when saved to the desktop.  We have one log stamp:

PHP Warning:  base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Any ideas on how to get this working please?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? `base64_decode` wants a string value as parameter, and what you are feeding it, isn't that.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you I have edited the post to change the log image to text.  I am unsure how to feed base64_decode a string value, the line of code came from the MS Graph documentation.  If I remove the base64_decode line I receive this error message from MS Graph:     the server returned an unexpected status code and no error class is registered for this code 400 {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"Cannot convert the literal '%PDF-1.6\r%\14 0 obj....

Comment: Not sure why base64 _decoding_ would be necessary here to begin with, aren't you reading from a file? The content of that would have to have been saved with additional base64 _encoding_ then to begin with, otherwise I can't see how that makes sense. // The Utils have methods such as `copyToString`, so use that if you really need the value in string form to pass it to base64_decode first.

Comment: `"Cannot convert the literal '%PDF-1.6\r%\14 0 obj` - but that data _is_ the actual binary content of a PDF file, and it is _not_ base64 encoded. So "decoding" it can't have achieved much in the first place, and is likely just masking another, different error, I suppose.

Comment: @Cbroe I got mixed up MS Graph needs the attachment encoded in base64 not decoded!  I will edit and post the working code above.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

MS Graph needs the data encoded not decoded! Working code:

```
$attachment = new FileAttachment();
$attachment->setName($emailAttachment['fileName']);
$attachment->setContentType(mime_content_type($emailAttachment['fileLocation']));
$resource = base64_encode(file_get_contents($emailAttachment['fileLocation']));
$attachment->setContentBytes(Utils::streamFor($resource));
$this->attachments[] = $attachment;
```